# No equivalent of Yes

Tags: linux

`yes` command in linux prints `y` infinitely on the console. This is helpful to respond to few interactive commands with `y`. For e.g. `yes | cp A/*.txt B` automatically overwrites all files in destination directory.

Is there an equivalent command in linux that prints `n` infinitely?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`yes` accepts an argument, `y` is just the default value.

You can use:

```
yes n | command
```

How cool is that?

---

Pro tip:

```
# Use this and see what happens
yes maybe | command
```

Note: Not every `command` implements `maybe`.

Comment: so there is something like yesn't in bash

Comment: What does the maybe one do? I can't find a command that accepts maybe